# Does a Hunter Ranger's Colossus Slayer feature affect ranged attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, ranged-attack

Creating a nemesis group for my current party. Figured I'd go with a WarForged Fighter, Wood Elf Ranger, and a human blue mage sorcerer at +1 the parties level.

Was going to make the ranger a hunter sub class and noticed the colossus slayer gives this:

> When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, the creature takes an extra 1d8 damage if it's below its hit point maximum ( 1/turn ).

I'm going to assume that this includes ranged weapons but thought I would ask just in case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes.**

The colossus slayer description uses the general term "weapon", and from the Weapons section in the PHB (page 146), melee and ranged weapons are considered weapons:

> Every weapon is classified as either melee or ranged. A **melee weapon** is used to attack a target within 5 feet of you, whereas a **ranged weapon** is used to attack a target at a distance.